# Snakeyaml load to JavaBean and if property is not found place in map

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I would like to know if it is possible to have snakeyaml load a yaml document into a javabean and if it is unable to find a match for the entry in the document as a javabean property it will place it into a generic map within the javabean...

Ex.

```
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private Map<String, Object> anythingElse;

  //Getters and setters...
}
```

If I load a document that looks like:

```
firstName: joe
lastName: smith
age: 30
```

Since age is not a property in the bean I would like {age, 30} to be added to the anythingElse map.

Possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No it wouldn't be possible.

From my experience and attempts it doesn't work. If you would want to load a file into a object than **all** attributes in that objectclass would have to have a getter and setter (I.E. the class have to be JavaBean, see Wikipedia).

I used your Person Class (See the wiki page for a proper JavaBeanClass) and this code: http://codepaste.net/dbtzqb

My error message was: "*Line 3, column 4: Unable to find property 'age' on class: Person*" thus proving that this simple program cannot have "unexpected" attributes. This is my fast and easy conclusion. I've not tried extensively so it may be possible but I don't know such a way (you'll have to bypass the readingmethods and JavaBean). I've used YamlBeans (https://code.google.com/p/yamlbeans/) so it's a little different but I find it easier and working ;]

Hope it's helping!

**Edit**

Sorry for bumping this, better late than never! I didn't see the postdate until after I posted my answer.. But hopefully it would help others seeking help assweel :3

Comment: Codepaste points to a broken link. This is why we should put the code directly here instead of on external websites.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the following (semi-kludgy hack) using SnakeYaml, but I have it working using YamlBeans:

Basically the idea is to define a class that extends one of the concrete implementations of java.util.Map. Then define getters that pick out distinct values and a general getter that returns everything else:

```
public class Person extends HashMap<String, Object>
{
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return (String)this.get("firstName");
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return (String)this.get("lastName");
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getExtensions()
    {
        Map<String, Object> retVal = (Map<String, Object>)this.clone();

        retVal.remove("firstName");
        retVal.remove("lastName");

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how either SnakeYaml or YamlBeans prioritizes the different type information you see when introspecting on this class, but YamlBeans (at least) is content to deserialize info into this class as if it were any other Map and doesn't seem to get confused by the addition getters (i.e. doesn't trip up on the "getExtensions").

Comment: I tried to get this working using SnakeYaml, but failed. For whatever reason, YamlBeans is easier to work with.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible:

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer;

public class YamlReader {
    public static <T> T readYaml(InputStream is, Class<T> clazz){
        Representer representer = new Representer();
        // Set null for missing values in the yaml
        representer.getPropertyUtils().setSkipMissingProperties(true);

        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(representer);
        T data = yaml.loadAs(is, clazz);

        return data;
    }
}
```